# Finding older versions of LinkedIn profiles

Tags: linkedin, cache

I saw a post from a LinkedIn user that is very important and therefore went back to the profile to find the post and it had been removed, presumably by the poster. I was wondering if they are ways to get the cache data from the website allowing me to see it. Iv tried the Way back Machine with no luck so was hoping someone could help me.

Comment: [Answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/119190/249248) from 2018, but it might still be valid.